# Local function string variable or outer global variable: which is more efficient?

Tags: c#, string

I have a very long c# windows form, and I need to use the same string in many places. Should I just define it or use a string in a local function?

e.g.

In the global outer function should I define the following:

```
static myUrl_A = "abc.com";
static myUrl B = "xyz.com";
```

or should I just use an inner string? Are there any other suggestions?

Comment: just note: use `constant` or `readonly` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If it's the same literal string, it doesn't matter. They're usually *interned*, which basically means that the compiler remembers the literals it's seen and all occurrences of the same one are a reference to a single string object in memory. It might still make sense to declare them somewhere to avoid having "magic numbers" in your code though.

Comment: i think global is better due to a lot of use, but if many function or thread calling the same global variable, is shouldn't have problem, right?

Comment: It shouldn't even be global - if you declare it `private` then no other class will be able to see it. It *should* be `static` though.

Answer (score 2):

As @millimoose mentioned, the performance implications are almost moot, although there are limits on when a string can be shared via interning.

More importantly, you really **should** have the string represented as a constant in a single place, if that string really only ever has a single value. There are two benefits to doing this:

1. You will not accidently give the same string different values in two different places (like typos).
2. If you *do* make a typo in the one location you specify it, you only need to change it there, not in the 20 files you copied it.

Answer (score 1):

Keep scope as small as possible – this makes your program logic easier to reason about (a variable that only exists in a small scope can only influence that scope, and be influenced by that scope).

There are virtually no performance implications for declaring many local variables instead of a few global ones. The exception being when your function is expected to recurse very deeply. But even then the overhead of a few local variable declarations can usually be neglected.